# Why am I unable to add an External Content Type as a column in my SharePoint List?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, external-contenttype

I've created an External Content Type that gets 2 columns of data from a SQL Server stored procedure now I'm trying to add it to a List I've created. When I select my External Content Type however I get the following error message:

"Business Data Connectivity object not found. Administrators, see the server log for more information."

When I go to the BDC Service section in Central Administration I see the External Content Type though. Any ideas?